# History does not have definition for function when trying to augment interface

Tags: typescript, react-router

I am trying to extend react-routers history with methods to support search parsing.

I've tried moving module definition and extension to separate files, importing history under different name since the name is colliding with global ts history definition.

```js
import { History } from "history";

declare module "history" {
    interface History {
        test: () => void;
    }
}

export function test(this: History) {
    console.log(this);
}

// History here is refering to lib.d.ts history for some reason
History.prototype.test = test; // ERROR: test does not exitst on preprty of type History<any>
```

Comment: Are the usage and the declare in the same file or different files?

Comment: @ShanonJackson usage is in the different file than declaration and it shows no errors, except when you run it, it doesn't have implementation.